# Tracking playing position into an array

Tags: transformation, coordinates, timer

I'm trying to track playing position every 500ms which i can do but i need it to populate an array which i save to a txt file as a comma delimted list or something.

I have this code so far (which incorporates the player movement code too), which displays the positions in the console:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterControllerT : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public Read_moveT ReadMove;
    [SerializeField] private float _duration = 0.5f;
    private float _timer = 0f;
    public Vector3 PlayerPosT;
    GameObject Mover;
    public Vector3[] PlayerTxyz;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Mover = GameObject.Find ("PlayerT");
        ReadMove = Mover.GetComponent<Read_moveT> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (!Input.GetButton ("DoorTrigger")) {
            ReadMove.mUP = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
            ReadMove.mLEFT = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
            float translation = ReadMove.mUP * speed;
            float straffe = ReadMove.mLEFT * speed;

            translation *= Time.deltaTime;
            straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

            transform.Translate (straffe, 0, translation);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("escape")) {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }


        _timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (_timer >= _duration) {
            _timer = 0f;
            PlayerPosT = Mover.transform.position;
            print ("Player:: X: " + PlayerPosT.x + ", Z: " + PlayerPosT.z);
        }
    }
}
```

I just need these coords to be saved into an array that i can process when the game is over. The problem being that the array will always be (until game over) of undetermined length.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Paul..

Comment: Have you considered a `List<Vector3>`? These can grow as needed to accommodate newly `Add()`ed entries.

Comment: Thanks @DMGregory. I didn't know about Lists - i'm new to c# :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a `List<Vector3>` and then when you need to save the position just call it with the List.Add(Vector3) like the following. Note that saving process better be done outside of your `CharacterControllerT` script in order not to lose the saved positions if you destroy the character or something.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PositionRecorder : MonoBehaviour {

    private static List<Vector3> savedPositions;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        savedPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    }

    public static void SavePosition(Vector3 position){
        savedPositions.Add(position);
    }
}
```

Then call it from outside like `positionRecorder.SavePosition(PlayerPosT)`

Comment: Thanks @Tolga Sen, I adapted a bit of your code to suit my needs and it works perfectly :) I just need to work out now how to create a line that joins the dots to create the path in a visual way but i'm sure i can work that out or might feed it to AutoCAD and create a polyline with the coords.

Comment: You are welcome, if you are stuck on that you can use LineRenderer component of unity and set the "points" field of LineRenderer object with your savedPositions. Check out manual:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html
and draw that wherever you like

Comment: One last comment, would you upvote the answer if that has worked for you?